# Retrieve Amazon Reviews for a particular product

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, amazon-product-api

I'm currently working on a research project which need to analyze reviews of a particular product and get an overall idea about the product.

I heard that amazon is a good place to get product reviews/comments. Is there any way to retrieve those user reviews/comments from Amazon via an API?? I tried several python codes but it doesn't work.. Do i need to write a spider if there is no API to retrieve data?

Are there any approaches/places to retrieve user reviews for a given product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.Scrapehero.com has a great tutorial on how to scrape Amazon product details: [How To Scrape Amazon Product Details and Pricing using Python](https://www.scrapehero.com/tutorial-how-to-scrape-amazon-product-details-using-python/)

The complete plain text code they use is ...
Products are identified by their ASIN so change the array values to the products you are interested in watching.

```
from lxml import html  
import csv,os,json
import requests
from exceptions import ValueError
from time import sleep

def AmzonParser(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
while True:
    sleep(3)
    try:
        doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
        XPATH_NAME = '//h1[@id="title"]//text()'
        XPATH_SALE_PRICE = '//span[contains(@id,"ourprice") or contains(@id,"saleprice")]/text()'
        XPATH_ORIGINAL_PRICE = '//td[contains(text(),"List Price") or contains(text(),"M.R.P") or contains(text(),"Price")]/following-sibling::td/text()'
        XPATH_CATEGORY = '//a[@class="a-link-normal a-color-tertiary"]//text()'
        XPATH_AVAILABILITY = '//div[@id="availability"]//text()'

        RAW_NAME = doc.xpath(XPATH_NAME)
        RAW_SALE_PRICE = doc.xpath(XPATH_SALE_PRICE)
        RAW_CATEGORY = doc.xpath(XPATH_CATEGORY)
        RAW_ORIGINAL_PRICE = doc.xpath(XPATH_ORIGINAL_PRICE)
        RAw_AVAILABILITY = doc.xpath(XPATH_AVAILABILITY)

        NAME = ' '.join(''.join(RAW_NAME).split()) if RAW_NAME else None
        SALE_PRICE = ' '.join(''.join(RAW_SALE_PRICE).split()).strip() if RAW_SALE_PRICE else None
        CATEGORY = ' > '.join([i.strip() for i in RAW_CATEGORY]) if RAW_CATEGORY else None
        ORIGINAL_PRICE = ''.join(RAW_ORIGINAL_PRICE).strip() if RAW_ORIGINAL_PRICE else None
        AVAILABILITY = ''.join(RAw_AVAILABILITY).strip() if RAw_AVAILABILITY else None

        if not ORIGINAL_PRICE:
            ORIGINAL_PRICE = SALE_PRICE

        if page.status_code!=200:
            raise ValueError('captha')
        data = {
                'NAME':NAME,
                'SALE_PRICE':SALE_PRICE,
                'CATEGORY':CATEGORY,
                'ORIGINAL_PRICE':ORIGINAL_PRICE,
                'AVAILABILITY':AVAILABILITY,
                'URL':url,
                }

        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print e

def ReadAsin():
# AsinList = csv.DictReader(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Asinfeed.csv")))
AsinList = ['B0046UR4F4',
'B00JGTVU5A',
'B00GJYCIVK',
'B00EPGK7CQ',
'B00EPGKA4G',
'B00YW5DLB4',
'B00KGD0628',
'B00O9A48N2',
'B00O9A4MEW',
'B00UZKG8QU',]
extracted_data = []
for i in AsinList:
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/"+i
    print "Processing: "+url
    extracted_data.append(AmzonParser(url))
    sleep(5)
f=open('data.json','w')
json.dump(extracted_data,f,indent=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
ReadAsin()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scrape regularly and go through several product pages, I would suggest to do an addition to the scape hero script and use https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/ for the "headers" in request.

Otherwise if it's just once in a while that you need to download the reviews you can use https://reviewi.me . It's a free, web bases tool, that works for several Amazon websites and allows to export in CSV, XLSX and JSON

Answer (score -1):

Beautiful Soup is a Python API that will allow you to rip the html data from a page, like an Amazon product page, and parse through the file. This API should allow for the review sections to be taken directly from the page. Here is a link to the documentation:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/